# How to connect multiple fields to another table

Tags: sql

I have three tables:

**INVITE:**

```
id (text)
fromGBId (text) 
toGBId (text)
```

note: `fromGBId` & `toGBId` refer to ids from GB table.

**GB:**

```
id (text)
userId (text)
```

note: `userId` refers to id from User table.

**User:**

```
id (text)
firstName (text)
```

How can I get the userId & firstName for both `fromGBId`, `toGBId`. I can only manage one (either join on `fromGBId` or join on `toGBId`) for now.

```
select
    "Invite" .id,
    "Invite" ."fromGBId",
    "Invite" ."toGBId",
    "GoalBoard".id as "gBFrom",
    "User" ."firstName",
    "User".id
from
    "Invite"
    full outer join "GoalBoard" on "Invite"."fromGBId" = "GoalBoard".id 
    full outer join "User" on "GoalBoard"."goalOwnerId" = "User".id;
```

Thank you

Comment: JOIN once for from, and JOIN once for to.

Comment: thank you, I tried that, couldnt get it to work with the error: `table name GB specified more than once`

Comment: You need different table aliases. E.g. `... join "GoalBoard" gb1 on "Invite"."fromGBId" = gb1.id ...`.

Comment: thank you, that worked. Have added the solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

As per Jarlh's kind help, got it working as follows:

```
select
    "Invite" ."fromGBId",
    "Invite" ."toGBId",
    gb1.id as "gBFrom",
    gb2.id as "gBTo",
    u1."firstName" as "fromFirstName",
    u2."firstName" as "fromFirstName",
from
    "Invite"
    full outer join "GoalBoard" gb1 on "Invite"."fromGBId" = gb1.id 
    full outer join "GoalBoard" gb2 on "Invite"."toGBId" = gb2.id 
    full outer join "User" u1 on gb1."goalOwnerId" = u1.id
    full outer join "User" u2 on gb2."goalOwnerId" = u2.id;
```